# Splitting a pdf stored on Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to do the following in Python 3:

1. Take a .pdf file in a folder in a Azure gen2 storage account
2. Split .pdf into single pages
3. Save each page as a new file

I'm trying to do this with fsspec and spire.pdf but am getting the error "wrong type" when I try to pass the pdf file to spire.pdf (step 1!). This is the code (spire.pdf code taken from [here](https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/split-pdf-files-or-pages-with-python-7721b656d987)).

```
import fsspec
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *


with fsspec.open(f'abfss://container/folder/myfile.pdf', account_name=adls_account_name, account_key=adls_account_key) as fsspec_handle_read:
        big_pdf = fsspec_handle_read.read()

# Create a PdfDocument object
pdf = PdfDocument()
# Load a PDF file
pdf.LoadFromFile(big_pdf)
```

The error I get is:
ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

I can't seem to find out what file type spire is expecting, nor am I actually that confident as to what file type the document is being passed as at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> Splitting a PDF stored on Azure Blob Storage

The `LoadFromFile` method of the `PdfDocument` class expects a file path as its argument, not the contents of the file.

You can use the code below, which uses the `io` module to create a file-like object from the contents of the PDF file and save it to a temporary file. Then, pass the file path to the `PdfDocument.LoadFromFile` method. The PDF document requires metadata and page numbers, so it is necessary to pass the file name. The **`fsspec`** provides data in binary format only.

**Code:**

```py
import fsspec
import tempfile
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

adls_account_name="xxxx"
adls_account_key="xxxxx"

with fsspec.open(f'abfss://sample/User_Guide_StatPlanet.pdf', account_name=adls_account_name, account_key=adls_account_key) as fsspec_handle_read:
    big_pdf = fsspec_handle_read.read()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
    temp_file.write(big_pdf)
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
pdf = PdfDocument()
pdf.LoadFromFile(temp_filename)
pdf.Split("SplitByEachPage-{0}.pdf", 1)

os.remove(temp_filename)
pdf.Close()
```

The code above uses **`fsspec`** to access the PDF file, creates a temporary file to write the contents of the PDF to, and then loads the PDF into a PdfDocument object. The code then splits the PDF into individual pages and saves each page as a separate PDF file. Finally, it removes the temporary file and closes the PdfDocument object.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Spire.PDF-for-Python/Examples/13_Document at main · eiceblue/Spire.PDF-for-Python · GitHub](https://github.com/eiceblue/Spire.PDF-for-Python/tree/main/Examples/13_Document)